# Что использовать для создания перманентного хранилища в Kubernetes?

Tags: devops, kubernetes

**Задача:**

- Необходимо создать постоянные хранилища для `mysql` и `mongo`.

В качестве провайдера файловой системы взял [NFS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System).

Для создания хранилища, что можно подключить к `поду` нужно создать [PersistentVolumeClaim](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/).
И еще нужно создать само хранилище:

**Тут вопрос:**

[PersistentVolume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) или [StorageClass](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/)?

Что будет лучшим решением применительно к задаче? Нужна ли тут абстракция в виде `StorageClass`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш вопрос не совсем корректен.

`PVC` это запрос на выделение определенного хранилища

`StorageClass` это *тип выделяемого хранилища*
это может быть NFS, Ceph, и.т.д, у вас может быть несколько провайдеров и вы выбираете в каком вам надо создать хранилище через StorageClass